# Facebook PHP publish watches action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to add the Facebook open graph feature to my website. I already created an action `(watch) a (video)`. Also I have set up my meta tags like so:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="namespace:video"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.zzz.com/images.php?i=something"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.zzz.com/thumbnails/images.png"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="desc"/>
```

I am using the PHP SDK to authenticate the users and now on the videos page I want to publish the users actions like so:

```
require_once('scripts/facebook.php');
        $config = array('appId' => 'xxxxxx','secret' => 'xxxxxxx');
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $facebook_user = $facebook->getUser();
        $facebook_message = array('message'=>$image_caption, 'link'=>'www.zzz.com/videos.php?i='.$video_name.'');
        if($facebook->getUser()){
            try{
                $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                $params = array('video'=>'http://www.zzz.com/','access_token'=>$access_token);
                $publish = $facebook->api('/me/namespace:watch','post',$params);
                }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                        error_log($e->getType());
                        error_log($e->getMessage());
                    } 


            }
```

Anyway when I run this code nothing is happening? Please tell me if I am wrong somewhere or  if I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t have *custom* watch actions any more, you have to use the build-in one.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#watch